# HTML form not submitting to php script

Tags: php, html, forms, action

UPDATE: The code works in Microsoft Edge, but not Firefox. Testing other browsers. Why would this not work in Firefox? END UPDATE

I am pretty new at PHP scripting, and I don't know if I got this right or not, can someone please check for me? My php script isn't being accessed by this form at all. Php script is in the right directory. Page just refreshes after clicking submit.

```
<form action="php/contact.php" method="post">
<div id="contactInfo"
data-anijs="if: mouseover, on: #contactContent, do: zoomIn animated, after: holdAnimClass">
<div>
<input id="contactName" name="contactName" class="contactField" type="text"
placeholder="Name"></div>
<div>
<input id="contactEmail" name="contactEmail" class="contactField" type="text"
placeholder="Mail"><span id="errorEmail" class="errorContact">Not a well-formed email address</span>
</div>
</div>
<div id="contactMsg"
data-anijs="if: mouseover, on: #contactContent, do: zoomIn animated, after: holdAnimClass">
<textarea id="contactMessage"  name="contactMessage" class="contactField" placeholder="Message"></textarea><span id="errorMsg" class="errorContact">Please enter a message</span>
</div>
<div class="sendContactContainer"
data-anijs="if: click, on: #sendContact, do: rollOut animated; if: mouseover, on: #contactContent, do: zoomIn animated, after: holdAnimClass">
<button id="sendContact" type="submit" name="sendContact"></button>
</div>
</form>
```

Comment: Have you placed your `contact.php` file in `php` folder. Check the file location of `contact.php`

Comment: It's perfect for send data in php folder in `connect.php` file.

Comment: Thanks guys, yea contact.php is in the php folder. The email.php script for adding emails to an email database, and also sending an email to my inbox to let me know I have a new subscriber works just fine, which is whats confusing me about this one.

Comment: if everything is working fine, what is your question?

Comment: Arshad, its my new subscriber form that's working fine, not this contact form that I'm trying to get to work. This form doesnt call the php script when i click on the submit button.

Answer (score 0):

I have tested your code. It works well but I think this is what you got wrong: you forgot to put name for button.

`<button id="sendContact" type="submit" name="sendContact">Submit</button>`

Comment: the submit button has text in place through a graphical submit button defined in my CSS so I don't need to have the actual text in place. Code still isnt working for me.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that your link in the action attribute works. If the relative link in your action attribute `php/contact.php` is not working, try changing the link to absolute link such as `http://www.example.com/php/contact.php` or if you are in localhost, depending on the situation, the link may be `http://localhost/main_folder/php/contact.php`. Use a variable or constant of a basic URL so you don't need to change link whether you are in localhost or live server.

At lest give some text to the submit button:

```
<button id="sendContact" type="submit" name="sendContact">Submit</button>
```

Comment: Thanks for the attempt but neither of those options worked. The only thing that's happening when I click the submit button is my page refreshing. The php script, just to test that it's working, currently only consists of an echo command so i can see instantly if it's even being called and no dice.

Comment: No it's not happening. I tested it.

Comment: The button is defined through CSS, that isn't be the issue. Even with text there it still fails.

Comment: No it works perfectly fine. Is there JavaScript stooping your code to function?

Comment: There shouldn't be. I have another form on the page that's accessing another php script just fine, so why wouldnt this one?

Comment: Here's exactly what my whole contact div looks like:      https://i.gyazo.com/f50288f5047311e9a3bd188714bcc101.png

Comment: Then why it works for me? Your code is working for me, accessing the php file and echoing out the text in the php file. Copy and paste your full page with both forms.

Comment: If I had that answer, Saral, I wouldn't be here. I'm at a complete loss. At this point, I'm willing to share my whole HTML file with someone that thinks they can help.

Answer (score 0):

Try your button code like this. I hope this will work.

```
<button id="sendContact" type="submit" name="sendContact" value="sendContact_data">Submit</button>
```